# How to move bones with quaternions on realdata

Tags: bones, transforms, quaternion

sorry for stupid questions, I am new on blender..

My question is how can i move bones when i recive data via serial port.
So i get quaternion via serial port and want to set the values on the bones.

i tried it like this but it does not work, but the part without blender is working with python.

```
import bpy
from math import *
from mathutils import *
import serial


class q:
    def __init__(self, id, w, x, y, z):
        self.id = id
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


class offset:
    def __init__(self, sender, x_accel, y_accel, z_accel, x_gyro, y_gyro, z_gyro):
        self.sender = sender
        self.x_accel = x_accel
        self.y_accel = y_accel
        self.z_accel = z_accel
        self.x_gyro = x_gyro
        self.y_gyro = y_gyro
        self.z_gyro = z_gyro


ser = serial.Serial('COM11', 115200)
if (ser.isOpen()):
    while True:
        a = ser.readline()
        aa = a.decode()
        # print(a)
        # print(aa)
        einzeldaten = aa.split(",")
        # print(einzeldaten)
        while n <= 3:
            if einzeldaten[0] == "Hand":
                q_Hand = q(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4])
                #print(q_Hand.id, q_Hand.w, q_Hand.x, q_Hand.y, q_Hand.z)
            elif einzeldaten[0] == "UnderArm":
                q_UnderArm = q(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4])
                # print(q_UnderArm.id, q_UnderArm.w, q_UnderArm.x, q_UnderArm.y, q_UnderArm.z)
            elif einzeldaten[0] == "UpperArm":
                q_UpperArm = q(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4])
                #print(q_UpperArm.id, q_UpperArm.w, q_UpperArm.x, q_UpperArm.y, q_UpperArm.z)
            #elif einzeldaten[0] == "Hand_Off":
                #offset_Hand = offset(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4],einzeldaten[5], einzeldaten[6])
                # print(offset_Hand.sender, offset_Hand.x_accel, offset_Hand.y_accel, offset_Hand.z_accel,offset_Hand.x_gyro, offset_Hand.y_gyro, offset_Hand.z_gyro)
            #elif einzeldaten[0] == "UnderArm_Off":
                #offset_UnderArm = offset(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4],einzeldaten[5], einzeldaten[6])
                # print(offset_UnderArm.sender, offset_UnderArm.x_accel, offset_UnderArm.y_accel,offset_UnderArm.z_accel, offset_UnderArm.x_gyro, offset_UnderArm.y_gyro,offset_UnderArm.z_gyro)
            #elif einzeldaten[0] == "UpperArm_Off":
                #offset_UpperArm = offset(einzeldaten[0], einzeldaten[1], einzeldaten[2], einzeldaten[3], einzeldaten[4],einzeldaten[5], einzeldaten[6])
                #print(offset_UpperArm.sender, offset_UpperArm.x_accel, offset_UpperArm.y_accel,offset_UpperArm.z_accel, offset_UpperArm.x_gyro, offset_UpperArm.y_gyro,offset_UpperArm.z_gyro)

            bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()

            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion[0] = q_UpperArm.w
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion[1] = q_UpperArm.x
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion[2] = q_UpperArm.y
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion[3] = q_UpperArm.z

            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[0] = q_UnderArm.w
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[1] = q_UnderArm.x
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[2] = q_UnderArm.y
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[3] = q_UnderArm.z

            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.002"].rotation_quaternion[0] = q_Hand.w
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[1] = q_Hand.x
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[2] = q_Hand.y
            bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_quaternion[3] = q_Hand.z

else:
    print("Port not open")
```

Maybe someone is so nice and can help me and point me to the right direction

Thanks and best regards

Comment: What 'does not work'?  That is, what happens to your object when it receives data and blender is running?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I tried to do that stuff with other programms but i found no way. My problem is, that the bones only move after i stop the script. How to update the bones with my quaternions live? thanks